Problems with Hibernate startup logging after adding JPA with database in SpringBoot version 3.4.0
The specific issue log output is as follows:
2024-12-03T16:52:53.338+08:00  INFO 34784 --- [blog] [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.orm.connections.pooling    : HHH10001005: Database info:
    Database JDBC URL [Connecting through datasource 'HikariDataSource (HikariPool-1)']
    Database driver: undefined/unknown
    Database version: 9.0.1
    Autocommit mode: undefined/unknown
    Isolation level: undefined/unknown
    Minimum pool size: undefined/unknown
    Maximum pool size: undefined/unknown


I searched on SpringBoot's issus, but SpringBoot says it's a Hibernate issue.And there is no useful reply from Hibernate side.
Please let me know if you know a specific solution.Thank you!

There is no issue. That is just INFO from hibernate as the pool isn't configured by hibernate it doesn't know all those parameters hence undefined.

There is no issue! That is just an information message printed by Hibernate through the ConnectionInfoLogger implementation in use. This will use the output of the DatabaseConnectionInfoImpl to output some information. All of this is triggered by the JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.
As Hibernate itself doesn't manage the connection pool it doesn't know much and hence it displays undefined for most properties (as those are part of the external configuration for the DataSource).
So in short the message you are seeing does not indicate any problem and is just informational. If you have issues those are not related to the message you are seeing here.

Okay, thank you! ❤
