Spring Boot: 'Database Driver: unknown/undefined' Error While Connecting to MySQL Database
pom.xml
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId> 
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

Application.properties
spring.application.name=SpringWebApp
server.port=8089

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/my_db
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update

Controller.class
package com.samna.SpringWebApp.controller;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.DeleteMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PutMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.samna.SpringWebApp.model.Product;
import com.samna.SpringWebApp.service.ProductService;


@RestController
public class ProductController {
    
    @Autowired
    ProductService service;
    
    @GetMapping("/products")
    public List<Product> getProducts(){
        return service.getProducts();
    }
    
    @GetMapping("/products/{pid}")
    public Product getProductById(@PathVariable int pid){
        return service.getProductById(pid);
    }
    
    @PostMapping("/products")
    public void addProducts(@RequestBody Product product) {
        service.addProducts(product);
    }
    
    @PutMapping("/products")
    public void updateProduct(@RequestBody Product product) {
        service.updateProduct(product);
    }
    @DeleteMapping("/products/{pid}")
    public void deleteProduct(@PathVariable int pid) {
        service.deleteProduct(pid);
    }

}

Repository
package com.samna.SpringWebApp.repository;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.samna.SpringWebApp.model.Product;

@Repository
public interface ProductRepository extends JpaRepository<Product, Integer>{

}

Entity
package com.samna.SpringWebApp.repository;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.samna.SpringWebApp.model.Product;

@Repository
public interface ProductRepository extends JpaRepository<Product, Integer>{

}

The application starts without throwing any explicit errors. However, the logs show that the database driver is "undefined/unknown," and I am unable to add data to my MySQL database.
Database JDBC URL [Connecting through datasource 'HikariDataSource (HikariPool-3)']
    Database driver: undefined/unknown
    Database version: 9.0.1
    Autocommit mode: undefined/unknown
    Isolation level: undefined/unknown
    Minimum pool size: undefined/unknown
    Maximum pool size: undefined/unknown


The problem seems to be in your application.properties
you may try it;
spring.application.name=SpringWebApp
server.port=8089

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/my_db?useSSL=false
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update


There is no problem, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79246915/problems-with-hibernate-startup-logging-after-adding-jpa-with-database-in-spring/79247018#79247018
